# No write permission on a mounted NTFS drive

Tags: 20.04, mount, ntfs

I have a dual boot system and multiple drives created in SSD. One partition is "Data" partition created from windows system and is of type NTFS.

While accessing this drive from my Ubuntu OS, I am not able to do any modification i.e. create/delete.

Note: Until few days back I was able to create folder and write to this partition. Since I am able to read files from it and also copy to my primary partition of Ubuntu. So I think mounting is proper. Also I can see I have full permission on folders inside this drive.

System Details: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Please let me know if more details are required related to this.

Comment: try to turn of the fast startup feauture in windows 10 https://www.windowscentral.com/how-disable-windows-10-fast-startup - see https://www.linuxuprising.com/2019/01/fix-windows-10-or-8-partition-mounted.html

Comment: @Koen thanks man it worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the proper link to this issue...
[How to make the mounted ntfs partition read-write enabled](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation)

In my case it was the fast startup feature of the Windows that was causing this issue.

Only thing which I was not able to figure out was it happened unexpectedly since things were working fine and without any change in windows it stoped working, it shouldn't have worked in the very beginning too.

Anyways problem is resolved now.

Thanks @Koen for your comment.

Comment: I had a dual boot system with WIndows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, and had the same issue. The only thing I could never think of was this issue! Hopefully, this instruction solved my issue.

Comment: This solved my problem. I had fresh install and there was little possibility of corrupt files that requires the attention of ntfsfix. It is a good idea to check this solution first, before getting into the ntfsfix solution.

Answer (score 2):

For those of you on Ubuntu 22.04, set the type of the filesystem to **ntfs3** in fstab.