# No permission to copy file to Windows Directory

Tags: copy-and-paste

I'm the one and only administrator of my system. I wanted to copy about a 22GB file to windows directory(C:\users\user_name\saved_games). But UBUNTU said that I have no permission to copy file there. Again I tried to copy a song of about 6MB and it worked. So why not 22GB? I need that file in WIndows. How to do that? Thank You.

Comment: A couple of answers to look at here:  https://askubuntu.com/a/145904/231142 and https://askubuntu.com/a/1309939/231142